# ordering y axis with facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data frame

```
library(dplyr)
dat =data.frame(parent = c("J","J","F","F"),group= c("A(4)","C(3)","A(4)","D(5)"),value=c(1,2,3,4),
                count = c(4,3,4,5))
dat %>% arrange(parent,-count )

 parent group value count
1      F  D(5)     4     5
2      F  A(4)     3     4
3      J  A(4)     1     4
4      J  C(3)     2     3
```

You can see above that the data is ordered by parent and then count descending. I would like the chart to keep this ordering BUT when I plot it in the "J" chart C(3) comes on top of A(4) and that should be revered. How can that be done?

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = group, y= value))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity",position = "dodge")+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~parent, scale = "free_y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your factor on the group column using the currently ordered values as the levels (reversed to get the ordering you want). This will lock in the ordering.

```
library(dplyr)
dat =data.frame(parent = c("J","J","F","F"),group= c("A(4)","C(3)","A(4)","D(5)"),value=c(1,2,3,4),
                count = c(4,3,4,5))
dat <- dat %>% arrange(parent,-count )

dat$group <- factor(dat$group, levels = rev(unique(dat$group)))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = group, y= value))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity",position = "dodge")+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~parent, scale = "free_y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
dat %>% arrange(parent,-count ) %>% 
  mutate(group2=factor(c(2,1,4,3))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group2, y= value))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity",position = "dodge")+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~parent, scale = "free_y")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=1:4,labels = c("A(4)","D(5)","C(3)","A(4)"))
```