# How to change y-axis labels in facet grid plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know this question has been [asked/answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262497/fixing-the-order-of-facets-in-ggplot) other places but I am very confused with how/where to apply code to reorder variables on my y-axis in a facet grid.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  type   = c("Small", "X-large", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "X-large", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "X-large", "Medium", "Large"), 
  group   = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  value = c(22, 40, 31, 60, 26, 24, 22, 18, 30, 70, 60, 50)
)
```

Figure:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(y=type, size = 15)) + facet_grid(group ~ ., scales="free_y", space="free_y")
plot <- plot + geom_point(aes(x=value),
                    size=3)
plot
```

[image]

What I would like is for the variables on the y-axis for each facet to go in a different order (small, medium, large, x-large) from top to bottom (instead of current order: x-large, small, medium, large). How do I change this? I understand my answer should look something like this:
`df$new = factor(df$type, levels=c("Small","Medium","Large","X-large"), labels=c("Small","Medium","Large","X-large"))` 
but I am not sure where to put this into my figure code. I tried putting it where 'type' is but that didn't work... Any help wold be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to change the labels just change the factor levels (`df$type = factor(df$type, levels=c("Small","Medium","Large","X-large"))`) and repeat the same code that you have.

Comment: Sorry that this was a duplicate question. Thank you so much @RonakShah, that worked, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question so it will be closed, but this example should help you understand the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  type   = c("Small", "X-large", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "X-large", "Medium", "Large", "Small", "X-large", "Medium", "Large"), 
  group   = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  value = c(22, 40, 31, 60, 26, 24, 22, 18, 30, 70, 60, 50)
)

df$type <- factor(df$type, levels = c("X-large", "Large", "Medium", "Small"))

ggplot(df, aes(y=type, size = 15)) + 
  facet_grid(group ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")+
  geom_point(aes(x = value), size = 3)
```

[image: example_1.png]

Comment: I don't believe that's the right duplicate, the question is about the order of the axis labels, not of the facets. As for the answer, it solves the problem, upvoted.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thanks @RuiBarradas, I got it wrong. Thanks for pointing out my error - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973678/ordering-y-axis-with-facet) is the duplicate.

Comment: Yes! Thank you @RonakShah, I didn't know about community wiki answers. That is exactly what I should have done in this situation - thanks for the help!